# "zooming" listview center row - android

Tags: android, listview, height, row

I've got a listview with a custom adapter, with all the rows having the same height(the rows only contain a picture and a textview).
Now I want to edit it so that the "middle" row viewed in the current display gets bigger(increase the height) and the rows below and above become smaller. (something like zooming the middle row)

I thought this could be achieved in the row layout, but no luck.

I'm pretty new to android programming so I have no clue how to approach this, I don't even know if it is possible to do this with a listview or if I should use something else to achieve this.

Just looking for a push in the right direction, since I had no luck on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want your center row to be zoomed even after scroll do following:

in you `activity` call

```
int visibleChildCount = (listView1.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView1.getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
```

and send `visibleChildCount` to your adapter.

In your `getView()` method

```
   if(position==visibleChildCount/2){
      //change height of row using linearLayoutParam
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible suggestion: create a new view that mimics the look of your zoomed table cell view and launch this view from the onOptionsItemSelected method. You could possibly even use the table data source to create some fake "unzoomed" neighboring cells surrounding the zoomed cell. Of course, this mock table view wouldn't be scrollable, but you didn't indicate if this was part of your criteria.