# Zooming Center ListView Element in android?

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview, textview

[Note: I've filled this up with code in the hope that this might help someone to easily implement a simple yet amazing looking list menu]

I'm trying to Enlarge the Centre most listview item. (Eventually, I hope to expand this into a sort of simple and light 3D effect that elements will appear to zoom in when in the middle of the screen and zoom out when they are down below, Total black background and text items zooming in and out... )

So, I've made a dummy listview, Each row is a textview element. Below, I have a custom Adapter.

The only relevant modification I've done is:

In the OnCreate(), I pass the following variable to the adapter:

```
int v = (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() - listview.getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
```

And in the Adapter's getView(), I've got this :

```
if (position == x/2) {
        textView.setHeight(100);
    }
```

Anyways here's all of the code, I've skipped the imports:
(It's not that big !... most of it is quite general : I've take it from these sources:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

["zooming" listview center row - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288032/zooming-listview-center-row-android)

)
   MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7","iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7","iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X" };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
        int v = (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() - listview.getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;


        final MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, v, R.layout.row, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }

        });
    }

}
```

MySimpleArrayAdapter.java

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final int x;

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int a, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.x = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if (position == x/2) {
            textView.setHeight(100);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And now the XML

Row.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And that is my entire project, Below is the ridiculous screenie my code gives.

**Problems**
Why is no text appearing? I clearly added the list values to the textview .

Why is the top most element big and not the middle one, I specifically set it to the middle one ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enlarging the middle element in a listview - android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205407/enlarging-the-middle-element-in-a-listview-android)