# Android Text Size large when it scroll

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, textview

I am working on an app, I am stuck on 1 point. I have 3 items in array an I want to show them in scrollview. But my problem is that whenever any text position comes in center its textsize will large. If position 0 comes in center its text will large like this [image]

and if position 1 is in center so like this [image]
and if position 2 is in center so like this [image]
 Please help me how can I do it? or any sample ??
Thanks

Comment: show your code what are doing

Comment: Pramod I didn't nothing on this right now, I want an idea to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

[Enlarging the middle element in a listview - android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205407/enlarging-the-middle-element-in-a-listview-android][1])

This is similar concept hope this will help you.