# Change size of the central item while scrolling using horizantalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

How to increase the size of central item while scrolling in horizontal scroll view?
Dynamically get images from server to when user scroll , central item size increased [image: Unable to design and implement this .]Unable to achieve above.
Any hint to implement this with other views instead of horizontal scroll view.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19205940/6201929

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive similar to this by using this library

https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

try to give visible item based on your screen size like this

```
 layoutManager.setMaxVisibleItems(1);
```

- 
 and you can change the  following listener as per you needs, by default they are providing a listener as com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager.CenterScrollListener.

```
layoutManager.setPostLayoutListener(new CarouselLayoutManager.PostLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public ItemTransformation transformChild(@NonNull View child, float itemPositionToCenterDiff, int orientation) {
            final float scale = (float) (1.5f * (1.5f * -StrictMath.atan(Math.abs(itemPositionToCenterDiff) + 1.0) / Math.PI + 1));
            final float translateY;
            final float translateX;
            if (CarouselLayoutManager.VERTICAL == orientation) {
                final float translateYGeneral = child.getMeasuredHeight() * (1 - scale) / 1f;
                translateY = Math.signum(itemPositionToCenterDiff) * translateYGeneral;
                translateX = 0;
            } else {
                final float translateXGeneral = child.getMeasuredWidth() * (0.8f - scale) / 1.5f;
                translateX = Math.signum(itemPositionToCenterDiff) * translateXGeneral;
                translateY = 0;
            }

            return new ItemTransformation(scale, scale, translateX, translateY);
        }
    });
```

hope this will help you...

Comment: my horizontal scroll lag while scrolling and center item looks like its jumping to position any idea why?